# DotNetOpenAuth not getting back email address from Facebook client?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth 4.3 for a current project. I believe as part of the default scope for the `FacebookClient` method it provides the `email` parameter. I verified that during the RequestAuthroization that Facebook is stating it will provide my email address and profile information.

[image]

Looking at the Request result I ***do not*** see the email address coming back in the Provider information or ExtraData property:

[image]
[image]

I did try adding the "email" to the scope implicitly.

```
public static class AuthenticationHelper
    {
        public static FacebookClient AuthFacebookClient()
        {
            String facebookKey = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            String facebookSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            return new FacebookClient(facebookKey, facebookSecret, new []{"email"});
        }
    }

public ActionResult Authentication()
        {
            var authString = Url.Action("AuthenticationResult", "Login",null,"http");
            var authUrl = new Uri(authString);

            var auth = AuthenticationHelper.AuthFacebookClient();

            auth.RequestAuthentication(HttpContext,authUrl);

            //should never reach this point
            return null;
        }

        public ActionResult AuthenticationResult()
        {
            var authString = Url.Action("AuthenticationResult", "Login", null, "http");
            var authUrl = new Uri(authString);
            var res = AuthenticationHelper.AuthFacebookClient().VerifyAuthentication(HttpContext, authUrl);
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Do I need to do something differently to make sure I get back the email address or does Facebook not send this information over?

**Upadate**

One thing i just noticed is that I am using the DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.FacebookClient. After looking at the source the Email address should be populated in the username key. Looks like facebook is setting the username, in my case, to my full name. I have no idea why.

**Yet another Update:**

I am beginning to think it may be a [Facebook Graph issue](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/61). After testing the account in their graph explorer I am noticing the email address is not coming back for some reason. According the the link I proved, this is a known issues and can depend on how the account was created or if the email address is not confirmed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that it was the account associated with Facebook. It was an older account and the email address was not confirmed correctly. Even after confirmation, it still was not showing up. Apparently, it was how the account was created in their system. So, what was recommend was to ask for the email address if you need it from the user.

Answer (score 2):

I use the below code on FacebookClient and worked for me (.net c#)

```
     var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token.Value);
dynamic me = fb.Get("/me?fields=email");

string email = me.email;
```